# Finding rows that start with a and b in SQLITE?

Tags: sqlite

Im trying to find all rows that start with J or M in sqlite. For example in Microsoft Access I know you can use :

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE cust_name LIKE '[JM]%';
```

However Im not sure what the equivalent of [] is in sqlite. I have 
tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE cust_name LIKE 'J%' OR 'M%'
ORDER BY cust_contact;
```

But this only returns rows that start with J :/ Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want row starts with J and M?

Comment: Use `WHERE cust_name LIKE 'J%' OR cust_name LIKE 'M%'`, because in your code `M%` is interpreted as FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

Or use [GLOB](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) instead of LIKE, but it is case sensitive and uses a different syntax.

```
WHERE cust_name GLOB '[JjMm]*'
```

LIKE is case sensitive unless options have been set otherwise, like `PRAGMA case_sensitive_like = boolean;`.  Although case sensitivity can be set for LIKE, GLOB is always case sensitive.

Comment: It did work thank you very much!!!! I just had called the wrong column :/ My bad im new to coding :P

Answer (score 0):

**Try the following code**

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE cust_name LIKE 'J%' OR
      cust_name LIKE 'M%' 
ORDER BY cust_contact;
```

Comment: Try with and instead of or

Comment: Actually, this will most likely work. He's saying or but he needs and. Look at very top he said j or m. I understood that string will contain both j and m.

Comment: But it says "Starts with...".  A string can only start with one letter.  The two conditions are mutually exclusive, so it is logically impossible.

Comment: Hmm.. now I'm questioning myself. Do you know if sql use liner search or something else?

Comment: It's not about the algorithm of the search.  It is all about logic.  LIKE 'M%' matches a string that starts with M.  LIKE 'J%' matches a string that starts with J.  Now take the following string "Make".  You would get `TRUE AND FALSE`.  It will match LIKE 'M%' but will fail LIKE 'J%'.  Now take a string "Jake".    It will fail LIKE 'M%' and match LIKE 'J%'. This would return `FALSE AND TRUE`.  You will NEVER find a string which starts with both M and J.  "MJake" almost gets there and so does "JMake", but not quite.  Live long and prosper.

Comment: I hate to see the downvotes since you had it correct originally, so I edited it back to the valid solution.